# why does one less space in regex makes my sed go weird?

Tags: bash, sed

Here is an example of some regex I am trying to figure out. The goal is to strip out extra spaces and make it only one space between words via sed. The sample given has three spaces between *sdf* and *sdk*:

```
test@ubuntu:~/addr_book_script$ echo "est sdf   sdk" | sed 's/  */ /g'
est sdf sdk
test@ubuntu:~/addr_book_script$ echo "est sdf   sdk" | sed 's/ */ /g'
e s t s d f s d k
```

You will notice that the two `sed` statement only differs on the number of spaces before the *. The first statement had two spaces and it behaved exactly what I wanted.

The second statement had one space before the * and it stuck a space between each  letter and word.

I know the * means any number of occurrences of whatever-it-is-that-I-am-looking-for. What I don't understand is why the one space sed replace behaves the way it does.

Thanks

Comment: ` *` can match nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sed 's/ */ /g'
```

The regex `*` matches 0 or more occurrences of  (space).

1. At the start of the string a 0 space match is found and replaced by single space
2. After the first letter another 0 space match is found and replaced by single space and so forth.
3. After `est`, more than 0 space is found and replaced by single space

And so forth.

Another example:

```
~ >>> echo "est sdf   sdk" | sed 's/a*/ /g'
 e s t   s d f       s d k
```

The replacements are occurred because of 0 character match.

Answer (score 1):

`" *"` (space-star) in regex means 0 or more occurrences of space and so it replaces every instance of 0 or more spaces with a space

`"  *"` (space-space-star) forces there to be at least one space

`" +"` (space-plus) would accomplish the same thing in some regular expression flavors, but not BRE